# PWA Cache Storage On Other Page Not Work?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I am developing pwa for my site and i store all assets to cache storage.
problem is when check dev tools -> application -> cache storage is ok and saved but when go to other page and switch to offline mod on dev tools cache storage not load !

cache storage data only loaded for same page that saved ?
other pages can not access to cache storage of other pages ?

```
 event.respondWith(
        fetch(request)
            .then(res => { // onLine
                if (request.method == 'GET') {
                    // add to cache
                    caches.open(DYNAMIC_STATIC_CACHE_NAME_VERSION)
                        .then(cache => {
                            // console.log("save to dynamic cache");
                            cache.put(request, res);
                        })
                        .catch(() => console.log("error on dynamic cache open!"));
                }
                return res.clone();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("user is offline");

                if (request.mode === 'navigate' ||
                    (request.method === 'GET' && request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html'))
                ) {
                    return caches.match(request) || caches.match(offlineUrl);
                }
                return caches.match(request) || fetch(request);
            });
```

Comment: When you say different page, what do you mean?

Comment: for example i am in / page(root of project) and save my data to Cache Storage. when go to /contact page and user mod is offline cache storage data not load !  but when user mod is online Cache Storage on /contact is ok and load.

Comment: i am check other site use pwa . They are like that

Answer (score 0):

Pages on the same domain share Cache API (and IndexedDB, LocalStorage etc) data.

Hence pages on different domains cannot access each other's Cache API data - this is a security mechanism.

Comment: my pages is same domain -  problem is cache storage on other page that user is offline  . i think is a bug on pwa.

Comment: and also i am test it on localhost